# rspec: Add feature specs to default spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, rspec3

I've got a rails 4.2 application with rspec-rails 3.5.1

I've got feature specs in `spec/features/<module>/<feature>_spec.rb`

When I run

```
bin/rspec
```

or

```
bin/rake spec
```

the feature specs do not run.

They run fine if I do

```
bin/rspec spec/features/*/*_spec.rb
```

How can I include this path in the default spec?

**Update**

Here's one of the specs in brief

```
require 'rails_helper'

Rspec.describe 'User logs in', :type => :feature do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  scenario 'with valid credentials' do

    ... setup ...

    expect(page).to have_content "Success"
  end
end
```

I've also tried replacing `Rspec.describe` with `describe`, `feature`, `Rspec.feature`. The spec doesn't run in the default specs.

Comment: How have you got your `Rspec.describe` set up at the top of your feature specs?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit and add an example.

Comment: Have you played around with the `--pattern` (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/command-line/pattern-option) you can setup a rake task to give that pattern to Rspec or you can configure it directly